# Cable trunking terminology

Tags: wiring, walls, receptacle, cables

I have a few cables running between my desk to a nearby tv screen and an electric outlet. I was thinking about tucking them in a pvc raceway stuck to the wall.
For a more tidy solution, I'm looking for some extension female port box that can be connected to the raceway. Id like to have power outlet, hdmi and rj45 ports in some sort of an exterior junction box on my desk.

Any idea on what components I might need for this project?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply. I didnt mean to get a shopping list, just figure out how to do it. How can I integrate an hdmi and power outlet ports into a box and connect a cable raceway to it. I am not familiar with the technical terminology for this project

Comment: You need some sort of product that will integrate all these connections; without that product, you'd be out of luck. So, IMO this falls under the "shopping" category. But: if you get an answer, and nobody else flags this to be closed, then my vote will be irrelevant.